# Reading and transferring encoder data from slave Arduino to master Arduino over SPI

Tags: arduino, spi, encoder

My goal is to transfer a speed value from an encoder from a slave Arduino to a master Arduino via SPI. I am currently getting zeros on the master side serial print and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I have increased the amount of time to wait several times to see if it was a processing time issue but I had it waiting for 100mS with still no change. I know an unsigned int is 4 bytes and I am unsure if a union is the best option in this case seeing I might be overwriting my data due to the separate interrupts but I am unsure. I thought to use a struct since I'll have to move to transferring an array of floats and ints over SPI from various sensors including this encoder later. Below is my code and thank you for any help received:

Slave

```
#include "math.h"
#define M_PI

byte command = 0;
const int encoder_a = 2; // Green - pin 2 - Digital
const int encoder_b = 3; // White - pin 3 - Digital
long encoder = 0;
int Diameter = 6; // inches
float previous_distance = 0;
unsigned long previous_time = 0;


void setup (void)
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(MOSI, INPUT);
  pinMode(SCK, INPUT);
  pinMode(SS, INPUT);   
  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT);

  // turn on SPI in slave mode
  SPCR |= _BV(SPE);

  // turn on interrupts
  SPCR |= _BV(SPIE);

  pinMode(encoder_a, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(encoder_b, INPUT_PULLUP);

  attachInterrupt(0, encoderPinChangeA, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(1, encoderPinChangeB, CHANGE);
 }  

// SPI interrupt routine
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
  union Data{
    float f;
    byte buff[4];}
   data;

  byte c = SPDR;

  data.f = assembly_speed();

  command = c; 

  switch (command)
  {
  // no command? then this is the command
  case 0:

    SPDR = 0;
    break;

  // incoming byte, return byte result
  case 'a':

    SPDR = data.buff[0];  
    break;

  // incoming byte, return byte result
  case 'b':

    SPDR = data.buff[1];  
    break;

  // incoming byte, return byte result    
  case 'c':

    SPDR = data.buff[2];  
    break;

  // incoming byte, return byte result    
  case 'd':

    SPDR = data.buff[3];  
    break;

  } 

}  

void loop (void)
{

  // if SPI not active, clear current command
  if (digitalRead (SS) == HIGH)
    command = 0;
}


void encoderPinChangeA() 
{
 encoder += digitalRead(encoder_a) == digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

void encoderPinChangeB() 
{
encoder += digitalRead(encoder_a) != digitalRead(encoder_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

float distance_rolled()
{
  float distance_traveled = (float (rotation()) / 8) * PI * Diameter;
  return distance_traveled;
}
int rotation()
{
  float eigth_rotation = encoder / 300;
  return eigth_rotation;
}

float assembly_speed()
{
 float current_distance = (float (rotation()) / 8) * PI * Diameter;
 unsigned long current_time = millis();
 unsigned long assemblySpeed = (((current_distance - previous_distance) / 
 12) * 1000) / (current_time - previous_time);  // gives ft/s
 previous_distance = current_distance;
 previous_time = current_time;
 return assemblySpeed;

}
```

Master

```
#include <SPI.h>

void setup (void)
{
    pinMode(MOSI, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MISO, INPUT);
    pinMode(SCK, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);

    Serial.begin (115200);
    Serial.println ();

    digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);

    SPI.begin ();

    SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);
 }

 byte transferAndWait (const byte what)
 {
  byte a = SPI.transfer (what);
  delayMicroseconds(10000);
  return a;
 } 

  union Data
  {
    float f;
    byte buff[4];
  }
  data;

void loop (void)
{

  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  transferAndWait ('a');  
  data.buff[0] = transferAndWait ('b');
  data.buff[1] = transferAndWait ('c');
  data.buff[2] = transferAndWait ('d');
  data.buff[3] = transferAndWait (0);

  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);

  Serial.print("data.f = ");Serial.print(data.f);Serial.println(" Ft/s");

  delay(200);
```

}